# In Objective-C, can we have a generic or base class reference to call different class methods?

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, can we have a class Foo and a class Bar, and then do something like

```
Class aClass = [Foo class];
[aClass getURLString];
```

where `getURLString` is a class method of the class Foo or Bar.  So in other words, invoke different class methods based on the class, and this class is referenced by a variable.

Foo and Bar have the same base class of NSObject in this example.  I tried using the code above and it won't work.  If I use

```
id aClass = Foo;
```

or

```
id aClass = [Foo class];
```

It won't work either.  Must I instantiate a dummy object?  Can Objective-C do it without instantiation?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? EDIT: also, `Class` and `id` are not compatible types, I don't think (May have to look that part up)

Comment: @CarlVeazey Class and id are indeed compatible, and it's a defining characteristic of Obj-C: classes are objects.  E.g., you can have an NSArray of classes; you can use -respondsToSelector: to see of a class object responds to a given class method; you can override class methods.

Comment: Nevermind, they are compatible types, my mistake.

Comment: @Darren you're right, I was blindly looking at the `struct` types they are typedef'd to be pointers to... but it looks like since both `objc_object` and `objc_class` start with the `isa` pointer, that's how they get treated the same by the run time, am I correct in that? Probably beyond the scope of a comment. But thanks for your correction, good explanation by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying should work fine. For example, the following works:

```
Class NSStringClass = [NSString class];
NSString *string = [NSStringClass string];
```

Is it possible you've neglected to `#import` the definition of `Foo`?

Comment: hm, it should that I defined the class method but didn't not include it in the `.h`...  so it seems to work now.